# Set controller variables from directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm quite new to Angular and having a bit of a struggle with understanding scopes it seems.

What I want to do is bind the contents of an `<input type="file">` to a variable in my controller. Since Angular doesn't seem to support this out of the box I am using [this custom directive](https://github.com/mistralworks/ng-file-model/blob/master/ng-file-model.js). I managed to display information about the selected file through a different DOM element like this (simplified) :

```
<div ng-controller="MyController as ctrl">
    <input type="file" ng-file-model="image"></input>
    <span ng-bind="image.name"></span>
</div>
```

So 'image' is now defined within the HTML context. I thought this was enough to also access the file in MyController in JS, but `$scope.image` is undefined. Furthermore, what I would ideally want to do is to avoid using `$scope` altogether and instead set a variable on my controller directly so that I can access it through `this.image` (in JS) or `ctrl.image` (in HTML).

All existing questions/answers about the topic seem to assume an incredible amount of knowledge about scopes already, so I'm hoping someone could tell me what the problem is (and what to do) in simpler terms ... thank you.

Comment: can you provide your code of controller ?

Comment: @zinfandel, replace your variable name `image` with `ctrl.image` in your html.

Comment: Thanks a million @Abhilash, it works. If you can tell me why `image` alone would not put it into the $scope variable I would be happy to accept that and your comment as an answer.

Comment: @You are casted your controller `as ctrl`. So now you should refer any variable inside your controller with `ctrl.`. If you just remove `as ctrl`, then you can just refer variable by `image`. Actually it represent `$scope.image` in the controller.

Comment: To use `this` keyword in your controller, use the `controllerAs` syntax. Here is a good article about it https://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/